# Commas with quotes that are inside a parenthesis

Tags: commas, quotes, parentheses

How would you punctuate the following and why?

> ("Grantor", whether one or more)

OR

> ("Grantor," whether one or more)

Comment: What's the full sentence?

Comment: What research have you done? If you google "commas quotation marks British American", for example, you'll find plenty of info.